# How to write a good Caps Lock detection solution in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url-rewriting

Found this Caps Lock detection solution. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/07ugkacn/11/ (Thank you Armfoot). JS/jQuery code here:

```
$(function () {
    var isShiftPressed = false;
    var isCapsOn = null;
    $("#txtName").bind("keydown", function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keyCode == 16) {
            isShiftPressed = true;
        }
    });
    $("#txtName").bind("keyup", function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keyCode == 16) {
            isShiftPressed = false;
        }
        if (keyCode == 20) {
            if (isCapsOn == true) {
                isCapsOn = false;
                $("#error").hide();
            } else if (isCapsOn == false) {
                isCapsOn = true;
                $("#error").show();
            }
        }
    });
    $("#txtName").bind("keypress", function (e) {
        var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
        if (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90 && !isShiftPressed) {
            isCapsOn = true;
            $("#error").show();
        } else {
            $("#error").hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Works perfectly for my needs. I'm trying to rewrite it in JavaScript though, with no jQuery. How do I rewrite the bind methods without the jQuery? I've tried storing the input fields in a variable and writing

```
passwordInput.onkeyup = function(e) { ... }
```

... For example. But to no avail. Think this is what's stopping this solution from working.

Help pls thx.

Comment: Why dont u check wheter 2 Letters, which are written after each other, are uppercase or not? Also when u dont like this solution, find out which keycode capslock has and check whether its on or not

Comment: This is not optimal. The user needs to know that caps lock is on when they click on the input, not after they started typing.

The problem is that a caps lock message displays after the user has turned caps lock off, and only hides after the user has typed at least one character. This is far form ideal.

The solution I've Control C'eed and V'eed works perfectly for my needs. I just need it in pure JavaScript with no JQuery.

Comment: My colleague doesn't want me to use jQuery on the project to minimize the scripts that load when this specific page loads. 

So yeah, that's what I'd like. To translate this. A lot of it seems fairly obvious to me, how it would be re-written without jQuery. I think it's the bind functions that are the problem. 

If you could tell me how to re-write said bind functions you will win the interwebs today.

Comment: also the script only checks whether the first letter written is uppercase with pressed shift.. if not CAPS is on ;) there u go combine this with my other 2 conditions mentioned above and u can do it on your own

Comment: It would be much easier to help you if you showed the code you've tried. Assigning a function to the onkeypress is the way to do it, so you'll have to show more of your code if you want to know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Specifically, I'm asking how to rewrite this as pure JavaScript :  $("#txtName").bind("keyup", function (e) { ... } 

If anyone else wishes to help O_O

Comment: @Gaweyne Yes, and that would be `document.getElementById('txtName').onkeyup = function(e) {...` If that doesn't work for you, you'll have to show your code.

Comment: Ok, I'll give it a go, and show my re-write if something's not working. I'm working on two machines :s

Comment: Edited the post to include my attempt at translating. And here is a fiddle of the solution in jQuery, to better illustrate what I'm trying to achieve: https://jsfiddle.net/Gaweyne/07ugkacn/

Comment: Your code works just fine with the `if(is CapsOn` typo fixed and with correct HTML. https://jsfiddle.net/07ugkacn/1/

Comment: Hunh. This works. But for some reason when you re-write it as JavaScript, the "Caps Lock" on message still displays after "Caps Lock" has been turned off. It only vanishes when I start typing something in the input field.

Some reason the jQuery version detects when the Caps Lock is active or not, that is, it doesn't wait until the user starts typing. 

But looking at your fiddle, and the jQuery solution I posted, I can't tell the difference between them.

What is this sorcery?

Comment: Btw Gaweyne, you can answer your own question with the solution you have found, so it may help others as well. [Here's the fiddle you provided](https://jsfiddle.net/07ugkacn/11/) with jQuery (HTML, CSS and JS code separated).

Comment: Ah. I went ahead and just edited my post and changed the title, to help others in a similar position find what they're looking for. 

But thanks for the tip.

Comment: The thing is, it will be more obvious to any user if your "question" has an "answer" (in stackoverflow terms) and you will also gain reputation ;)

Comment: Reputation eh? O_O

Ok I'll amend this when I have a free moment.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Figured it out on my own

For whom it may concern, a solution for caps detection in vanilla JavaScript. The problem with most of the solutions floating around on the internet is they only show/hide an alert/popup when the user starts typing in the input field. This is not optimal because the "Caps Lock is on" notification is still visible after the user has turned Caps Lock off, and remains so until they resume typing. This is long and unwieldy, and I still don't quite understand it myself. But I recommend it all the same.

```
function capsDetect() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var isShiftPressed = false;
  var isCapsOn = null;
  var capsWarning = document.getElementById('caps-lock-warning');
  body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if (keyCode = 16){
   isShiftPressed = true;
}
});
body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
 var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
 if(keyCode == 16) {
   isShiftPressed = false;
}
 if(keyCode == 20) {
  if(isCapsOn == true) {
   isCapsOn = false;
   capsWarning.style.visibility = 'hidden';
} else if (isCapsOn == false) {
  isCapsOn = true;
  capsWarning.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
}
});
body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
  if(keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90 && !isShiftPressed) {
    isCapsOn = true;
    capsWarning.style.visibility = 'visible';
} else {
    capsWarning.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
});
}
shiftCaps();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Gaweyne, nicely done](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31812921/1326147)! I tested your pure JS code and there are some things that I modified which you may find interesting:

- ignored control characters while typing (<= 40), such as directional and removal keys;
- replaced `if (keyCode = 16){` to `if (keyCode === 16){` and other `==` in the same way;
- used `display` property instead of `visibility` (CSS);
- considered `isCapsOn` as a boolean, always;
- called `capsDetected` instead of `shiftCaps`.

You can run the snippet below to check it out:

```js
function capsDetect() {
  var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
  var isShiftPressed = false;
  var isCapsOn = false;
  var capsWarning = document.getElementById('error');
  body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (keyCode === 16) {
      isShiftPressed = true;
    }
  });
  body.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (keyCode === 16) {
      isShiftPressed = false;
    }
    if (keyCode === 20) {
      if (isCapsOn) {
        isCapsOn = false;
        capsWarning.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        isCapsOn = true;
        capsWarning.style.display = 'inline-block';
      }
    }
  });
  body.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    var keyCode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which;
    if (keyCode <= 40)
      return;
    if (keyCode >= 65 && keyCode <= 90 && !isShiftPressed) {
      isCapsOn = true;
      capsWarning.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else {
      capsWarning.style.display = 'none';
    }
  });
}
capsDetect();
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 10pt;
}
#error {
  border: 1px solid #FFFF66;
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 3px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input id="txtName" type="text" /><span id="error">Caps Lock is ON.</span>
</form>
```

Maybe some more tweaking will make it perfect... There is still the CAPS LOCK detection on  page load: maybe by simulating user input in the background will let us know, but right now I haven't completely figured it out yet.

Btw, I never thought of doing this before, but it is clear that it helps users, specially in passwords fields. In fact, I may personally use it! So I really appreciate your time for posting this up :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the improvements! :D I'll keep this saved somewhere for when I want to do another Caps Lock notification elsewhere.

It was sheer dumb luck to be honest and tinkering with a solution I fond on a blog. Now I've had a day to think about it though I understand the thing I'm recommending everyone else do O_o